# Issue with animation of UITextView in a UIView

Tags: iphone, animation, uiview, uitextview

I have a setup in which I have my main `UIView`, within this I display another `UIView` which appears to slide & expand until fully in view. Within this new view I have a `UITextView`, however when I run the animation to make the `UIView` appear it doesn't seem to apply the animation to the `UITextView`. The effect of this is that the `UITextView` just appears in its final position straight away, the rest of the UIView then slides into place. Is there a way to make the animation apply to the widgets inside the view as well?

Here is the code I'm using at the moment.

```
[self.view addSubview:innerView];
[innerView setFrame:CGRectMake(29.5,127,261,0)];
[textView setFrame:CGRectMake(20,20,221,0)];
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:5.0];
[innerView setFrame:CGRectMake(29.5,127,261,275)];
[textView setFrame:CGRectMake(20,128,221,129)];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Please can someone help me out? I've been playing around with this problem for a long time now with no luck at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had similar behavior in one of my apps. It was due to the `autoresizingMask` on a UITextView. Also make sure your top UIView does not have `autoresizesSubviews` option enable as it will influence the behavior of your `UITextView` on animation.

Comment: Thanks for your advice - I managed to fix the issue using by using the method you suggested.